# double not being subtracted

Tags: java, android, andengine

I declare these two doubles at class level.

```
private double interval = 2;
private double interval2 = 3;
```

These two intervals control a second based timer.

Now during the code I have a `IUpdate` method that updates every second. Each second I check the user's score and if its a certain score I try to:

```
 interval = interval - .5
 interval = interval2 - .5;
```

I try to subtract .5 from the interval itself and supply the new `double` to my timer

```
 timer.setInterval(interval);
 timer.setInterval(interval2);
```

Now the only problem is im noticing that nothing gets subtracted from my variables. I log them when they are SUPPOSED to change but nothing happens. Is there something im missing here?

Comment: Should `interval = interval2 - .5;` be `interval2 = interval2 - .5;`? Also consider using the `-=` operator.

Comment: Yes it should but that the problem still persists.

Comment: @AusCBloke if you post that as an answer ill mark it correct. It fixed my issue..some how. lol

Comment: There's a reason for that, look at how you're setting the timer. Your second call cancels out the first one - check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
interval = interval2 - .5;
```

`interval` should be `interval2`, therefore `interval2` isn't being modified. The reason that the timer isn't changing is because `interval2` isn't being assigned a new value, and because the timer is always set to an interval of value `interval2`:

```
timer.setInterval(interval);
timer.setInterval(interval2);
```

The second call to `timer.setInterval()` cancels out the first one.

Comment: Got it. that makes perfect sense. Thanks